# "scala.MatchError" on Cypher CREATE query

Tags: php, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to insert a few nodes and edges into a **Neo4j** graph using **Cypher statements**. Upon executing the query, I get a not very meaningful `scala.MatchError` response from the server. I'm using Neo4j in **version 2.2.0**.

This is my Cypher query (note that it's originally part of a **much** larger query, but this is what I've narrowed it down to):

```
CREATE (node55549aefd9aa7:Arg {prop_node55549aefd9aa7})
```

Arguments for this query (in JSON notation):

```
{
  "prop_node55549aefd9aa7": {
    "startLine": 48,
    "endLine": 51,
    "type": 1,
    "byRef": false,
    "variadic": false,
    "name": "query",
    "default": null,
    "__node_id": "node55549aefd9aa7"
  }
}
```

This is the error response that I'm getting:

```
scala.MatchError: (default,null) (of class scala.Tuple2)  
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.mutation.CreateNode$$anonfun$org$$$$c818f6fea869bbb25aedba7c5faae2d$$$$e$$fromAnyToLiteral$1$1.apply(CreateNode.scala:40)
    at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.mutation.CreateNode$$anonfun$org$$$$c818f6fea869bbb25aedba7c5faae2d$$$$e$$fromAnyToLiteral$1$1.apply(CreateNode.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
// Several dozen lines of stack trace omitted
```

I'm using the [everyman/neo4jphp](http://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp) library for accessing Neo4j from my PHP application. I suspect that's of little relevance, though, because the error is also reproducible when speaking directly to the REST API using a simple cURL call on the command line:

```
curl -D - \
    --user neo4j:XXXX \
    -H "content-type: application/json" \
    -d'{"statements":[{"statement":"CREATE (node55549aefd9aa7:Arg {prop_node55549aefd9aa7})", "parameters": {"prop_node55549aefd9aa7": {"startLine": 48, "endLine": 51, "type": 1, "byRef": false, "variadic": false, "name": "query", "default": null, "__node_id": "node55549aefd9aa7"}}}]}' \
    http://localhost:7474/db/data/transaction/commit
```

**What does this error mean and why am I getting it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is actually a **bug report** for current Neo4j versions for this issue that is [discussed on GitHub](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/3870). What `scala.MatchError: (default,null)` **actually means** is that the `default` property has a `null` value, which is apparently invalid in Neo4j.

In `CREATE` statements, node properties **must not** contain `null` values. From reading the GitHub issue, I'm not really sure if this is by design (and it's simply the error message that is unclear) or an actual bug. In any way, the query can be executed successfully by simply omitting the `null` properties from the query arguments:

```
{
  "prop_node55549aefd9aa7": {
    "startLine": 48,
    "endLine": 51,
    "type": 1,
    "byRef": false,
    "variadic": false,
    "name": "query",
    # "default": null,  <-- Remove the "default" property!
    "__node_id": "node55549aefd9aa7"
  }
}
```

Luckily, defining properties as `null` or not defining them at all is **semantically equivalent** in Neo4j. This means that query constraints like `WHERE node.default IS NULL` will still match nodes where the `default` property is not defined at all.

On the application side, a simple filter construct can be used to prevent `null` values from being used as properties:

```
$properties = array_filter($properties, function($value) {
    return $value !== NULL;
}
```